# What's the difference between the 'ref' and 'out' keywords?

Tags: c#, reference, keyword, out, ref

I'm creating a function where I need to pass an object so that it can be modified by the function. What is the difference between:

```
public void myFunction(ref MyClass someClass)
```

and

```
public void myFunction(out MyClass someClass)
```

Which should I use and why?

Comment: You: ***I need to pass an object so that it can be modified*** It looks like `MyClass` would be a `class` type, i.e. a reference type. In that case, the object you pass can be modified by the `myFunction` even with no `ref`/`out` keyword. `myFunction` will receive a _new_ reference that points to the _same_ object, and it can modify that same object as much as it wants. The difference the `ref` keyword would make, would be that `myFunction` received the _same_ reference to the same object. That would be important only if `myFunction` were to change the reference to point to _another_ object.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the amount of confusing answers here, when @AnthonyKolesov's is quite perfect.

Comment: Declaring an out method is useful when you want a method to return multiple values. One argument can be assigned to null. This enables methods to return values optionally.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen's comment is, technically, the (only) correct answer to the OP's actual question. To pass an object into a method so that **the method can modify the object**, simply pass the (reference to the) object into the method by value. Changing the object within the method via the object argument **modifies the original object**, even though the method contains its own separate variable (which references the same object).

Comment: Here is key difference b/w out vs ref vs in

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iRPMrNY7OU&t=43s

Answer (score 1303, accepted):

`ref` tells the compiler that the object is initialized before entering the function, while `out` tells the compiler that the object will be initialized inside the function.

So while `ref` is two-ways, `out` is out-only.

Comment: Another cool thing specific to out is that the function has to assign to the out parameter. It's not allowed to leave it unassigned.

Comment: is 'ref' only applicable to value type? Since reference type is always pass by ref.

Comment: Yes. Value types including structs

Comment: @faulty: No, ref is not only applicable to value types. ref/out are like pointers in C/C++, they deal with the memory location of the object (indirectly in C#) instead of the direct object.

Comment: @faulty: Counterintuitively, Reference types are always passed by value in C#, unless you use the ref specifier. If you set myval=somenewval, the effect is only in that function scope. The ref keyword would allow you to change myval to point to somenewval.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: For functions *Implemented in C#*, the compiler will insist that `out` parameters must be written on all non-exceptional code paths; that is not enforced, however, for functions--including *virtual function overrides*--implemented in other languages.  It is entirely possible, for example, that an implementation of `IDictionary<TK,TV>.TryGetValue(TK, out TV)` will leave its `out` parameter unmodified when a value is not found.

Comment: There is a trick how to pass to a ref uninitialized object without any compile-time errors, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41736718/5612780)

Comment: Both ref and out cannot be used in method overloading simultaneously. However, ref and out are treated differently at run-time but they are treated same at compile time. CLR does not differentiate between the two in IL.

Comment: @BharathkumarV Isn't your comment backward? `ref` and `out` are treated differently at compile time but are treated the same at run time.

Comment: @thr just to clarify: ref/out are *not* like pointers in C/C++. Rather, just normal variables for objects are like pointers in C/C++. ref/out in C# is quite similar to the 'reference' in C++, which is absent in C.

Answer (score 635):

The `ref` modifier means that:

1. The value is already set and
2. The method can read and modify it.

The `out` modifier means that:

1. The Value isn't set and can't be read by the method *until* it is set.
2. The method *must* set it before returning.

Comment: This answer most clearly and concisely explains the restrictions that the compiler imposes when using the out keyword as opposed to the ref keyword.

Comment: From MSDN: A ref parameter must be initialized before use, while an out parameter does not have to be explicitly initialized before being passed and any previous value is ignored.

Comment: With `out`, can it be read at all within the method, before it's been set by that method, if it has been initialized before the method was called?  I mean, can the called method read what the calling method passed to it as an argument?

Comment: Panzercrisis, for "out",  the called method can read if it is already set. but it must set it again.

Answer (score 154):

Let's say Dom shows up at Peter's cubicle about the memo about the TPS reports.

If Dom were a ref argument, he would have a printed copy of the memo.

If Dom were an out argument, he'd make Peter print a new copy of the memo for him to take with him.

Comment: ref Dom would have written the report in pencil so that Peter could modify it

Comment: @Deebster you know, that metaphor never did anything to you, why must you torture it so? ;)

Comment: entertaining yet educating, stackoverflow needs more posts like this

Comment: Just in case somebody finds this answer only half-funny, please watch the movie "Office Space".

Comment: An excellent explanation. This is very helpful for students who struggle to understand the core concepts of C#. Keep it up :-)

Answer (score 68):

I am going to try my hand at an explanation:

I think we understand how the value types work right?  Value types are (int, long, struct etc.).  When you send them in to a function without a ref command it COPIES the **data**. Anything you do to that data in the function only affects the copy, not the original.  The ref command sends the ACTUAL data and any changes will affect the data outside the function.

Ok on to the confusing part, reference types:

Lets create a reference type:

```
List<string> someobject = new List<string>()
```

When you new up *someobject*, two parts are created:

1. The block of memory that holds data for *someobject*.
2. A reference (pointer) to that block
   of data.

Now when you send in *someobject* into a method without ref it COPIES the **reference** pointer, NOT the data.  So you now have this:

```
(outside method) reference1 => someobject
(inside method)  reference2 => someobject
```

Two references pointing to the same object.  If you modify a property on *someobject* using reference2 it will affect the same data pointed to by reference1.

```
 (inside method)  reference2.Add("SomeString");
 (outside method) reference1[0] == "SomeString"   //this is true
```

If you null out reference2 or point it to new data it will not affect reference1 nor the data reference1 points to.

```
(inside method) reference2 = new List<string>();
(outside method) reference1 != null; reference1[0] == "SomeString" //this is true

The references are now pointing like this:
reference2 => new List<string>()
reference1 => someobject
```

Now what happens when you send *someobject* by ref to a method?
The **actual reference** to *someobject* gets sent to the method.  So you now have only one reference to the data:

```
(outside method) reference1 => someobject;
(inside method)  reference1 => someobject;
```

But what does this mean?  It acts exactly the same as sending someobject not by ref except for two main thing:

1) When you null out the reference inside the method it will null the one outside the method.

```
 (inside method)  reference1 = null;
 (outside method) reference1 == null;  //true
```

2) You can now point the reference to a completely different data location and the reference outside the function will now point to the new data location.

```
 (inside method)  reference1 = new List<string>();
 (outside method) reference1.Count == 0; //this is true
```

Comment: You mean after all (in ref case) there's only one reference to data but two alias for it. Right?

Comment: Upvoted for the clear explanation. But I think this doesn't answer the question, as it do not explain the difference between `ref` and `out` parameters.

Comment: Amazing. can you explain same as for `out` keyword?

Answer (score 31):

[ref is in **and** out](http://luisabreu.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/parameters-by-reference/).

You should use `out` in preference wherever it suffices for your requirements.

Comment: not quite, as the accepted answer ref if directional and useless ignoring value-types if not passed back out.

Comment: @kenny: Can you clarify a bit please - i.e., which words would you change to maintain the spirit of the answer but remove the inacuracy you percieve? My answer is not a crazy guess from a newbie, but the haste (terseness, typos) in your comment seems to assume it is. The aim is to provide a way of thinking about the difference with the least number of words.

Comment: (BTW I'm familiar with value types, reference types, passing by reference, passing by value, COM and C++ should you find it useful to make reference to those concepts in your clarification)

Comment: I don't disagree, but only a minor nit with 'ref' only for input. I have 2 points. 1 objects are passed by reference always. And the second point is that you only would add a reference if you care what happens in side the method or it has side effects for the caller.  I think maybe I misread your answer in the context of the question, I read it as 'ref' is for in and 'out' is for out.

Comment: Object references are passed by value (except when using the "ref" or "out" keyword).  Think of objects as ID numbers.  If a class variable holds "Object #1943" and one passes that variable by value to a routine, that routine can make changes to Object #1943, but it can't make the variable point to anything other than "Object #1943".  If the variable was passed by reference, the routine could make the variable point hold "Object #5441".

Comment: @supercat: If you agree (didn't see a +1) and want to explain to @ kenny, you need to @ him in. If you want to explain the difference between references and values to me, you've just done that... If you feel this answer is wrong and needs rewriting based on your comment, feel free to edit and/or add your own answer.

Comment: @RubenBartelink: Thanks for the heads-up; I'd meant to notify Kenny.  I wish the "object ID" description were used more widely; I think it makes things very clear.  If a bodyshop worker is handed a piece of paper with a license number and asked to paint that car blue, he should be expected to find the car whose license matches the one on the paper and paint that, while leaving the number on the paper alone.  He would not be expected to paint the paper blue, nor re-ink it with blue lettering.

Comment: @supercat: I do like your explanation of ref vs val (and this followup anaology). I think kenny doesnt actually need any of this explained to him, (relatively) confusing as his comments were. I do wish we could all just remove these goddam comments though as they're just confusing everyone. The root cause of all this nonsense appears to be that kenny misread my answer and has yet to point out a single word that should be added/removed/replaced. None of the three of us have learned anything from the discussion we didnt already know and the other answer has a ludicrous number of upvotes.

Answer (score 23):

### out:

In C#, a method can return only one value. If you like to return more than one value, you can use the out keyword. The out modifier return as return-by-reference. The simplest answer is that the keyword “out” is used to get the value from the method.

1. You don't need to initialize the value in the calling function.
2. You must assign the value in the called function, otherwise the compiler will report an error.

### ref:

In C#, when you pass a value type such as int, float, double etc. as an argument to the method parameter, it is passed by value. Therefore, if you modify the parameter value, it does not affect argument in the method call. But if you mark the parameter with “ref” keyword, it will reflect in the actual variable.

1. You need to initialize the variable before you call the function.
2. It’s not mandatory to assign any value to the ref parameter in the method. If you don’t change the value, what is the need to mark it as “ref”?

Comment: "In C#, a method can return only one value. If you like to return more than one value, you can use the out keyword." We can also use "ref" for returning value. So we can use both ref and out if we want to return multiple values from a method?

Comment: In the c# 7 you can return multiple values with ValueTuples.

Answer (score 15):

**ref** means that the value in the ref parameter is already set, the method can read and modify it.
Using the ref keyword is the same as saying that the caller is responsible for initializing the value of the parameter.

---

**out** tells the compiler that the initialization of object is the responsibility of
the function, the function has to assign to the out parameter.
It's not allowed to leave it unassigned.

https://www.codemaggot.com/ref-and-out-keywords/

Answer (score 14):

Extending the Dog, Cat example. The second method with ref changes the object referenced by the caller. Hence "Cat" !!!

```
    public static void Foo()
    {
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        myObject.Name = "Dog";
        Bar(myObject);
        Console.WriteLine(myObject.Name); // Writes "Dog". 
        Bar(ref myObject);
        Console.WriteLine(myObject.Name); // Writes "Cat". 
    }

    public static void Bar(MyClass someObject)
    {
        MyClass myTempObject = new MyClass();
        myTempObject.Name = "Cat";
        someObject = myTempObject;
    }

    public static void Bar(ref MyClass someObject)
    {
        MyClass myTempObject = new MyClass();
        myTempObject.Name = "Cat";
        someObject = myTempObject;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

`ref` and `out` behave similarly except following differences.

- `ref` variable must be initialized before use. `out` variable can be used without assignment
- `out` parameter must be treated as an unassigned value by the function that uses it. So, we can use initialized `out` parameter in the calling code, but the value will be lost when the function executes.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're passing in a reference type (a class) there is no need use `ref` because per default only a **reference** to the actual object is passed and therefore you always change the object behind the reference.

Example:

```
public void Foo()
{
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
    myObject.Name = "Dog";
    Bar(myObject);
    Console.WriteLine(myObject.Name); // Writes "Cat".
}

public void Bar(MyClass someObject)
{
    someObject.Name = "Cat";
}
```

As long you pass in a class you don't have to use `ref` if you want to change the object inside your method.

Comment: This works only if no new object is created and returned.  When a new object is created, the reference to the old object would be lost.

Comment: This is wrong - try the following: add `someObject = null` to `Bar` end execute. Your code will run fine as only `Bar`'s reference to the instance was nulled. Now change `Bar` to `Bar(ref MyClass someObject)` and execute again - you'll get a `NullReferenceException` because `Foo`'s reference to the instance has been nulled too.

Answer (score 7):

For those that learn by example (like me) here's what [Anthony Kolesov is saying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388781/653939).

I've created some minimal examples of ref, out, and others to illustrate the point. I'm not covering best practices, just examples to understand the differences.

https://gist.github.com/2upmedia/6d98a57b68d849ee7091

Answer (score 6):

"Baker"

That's because the first one changes your string-reference to point to "Baker". Changing the reference is possible because you passed it via the ref keyword (=> a reference to a reference to a string).
The Second call gets a copy of the reference to the string.

string looks some kind of special at first. But string is just a reference class and if you define

```
string s = "Able";
```

then s is a reference to a string class that contains the text "Able"!
Another assignment to the same variable via

```
s = "Baker";
```

does not change the original string but just creates a new instance and let s point to that instance!

You can try it with the following little code example:

```
string s = "Able";
string s2 = s;
s = "Baker";
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

What do you expect?
What you will get is still "Able" because you just set the reference in s to another instance while s2 points to the original instance.

EDIT:
string is also immutable which means there is simply no method or property that modifies an existing string instance (you can try to find one in the docs but you won't fins any :-) ). All string manipulation methods return a new string instance! (That's why you often get a better performance when using the StringBuilder class)

Comment: Exactly.  So it's not strictly true to say "Since you're passing in a reference type (a class) there is no need use ref".

Comment: In theory it is right to say so because he wrote "so that it can be modified" which isn't possible on strings. But because of immutable objects "ref" and "out" are very useful also for reference types!
(.Net contains a lot of immutable classes!)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't think of immutable objects like strings because most object are mutable.

Comment: Well, this is a puzzling answer to see in LQP, to be sure; there's not a thing wrong with it except that it appears to be a long and thorough response to another comment (since the original question mentions Able and Baker in none of its revisions), as though this were a forum. I guess that wasn't really sorted out yet way back when.

Answer (score 6):

**For those looking concise answer.**

> Both `ref` and `out` keywords are used to pass-by-`reference`.
>
> ---
>
> A variable of `ref` keyword must have a value or must refer to an object
>   or `null` **before** its passing.
>
> ---
>
> Unlike `ref`, a variable of `out` keyword must have a value or must
>   refer to an object or `null` **after** its passing as well as no need
>   to have a value or refer to an object **before** passing.

Answer (score 5):

**Out:** 
A return statement can be used for returning only one value from a function. However, using output parameters, you can return two values from a function. Output parameters are like reference parameters, except that they transfer data out of the method rather than into it.

The following example illustrates this:

```
using System;

namespace CalculatorApplication
{
   class NumberManipulator
   {
      public void getValue(out int x )
      {
         int temp = 5;
         x = temp;
      }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         NumberManipulator n = new NumberManipulator();
         /* local variable definition */
         int a = 100;

         Console.WriteLine("Before method call, value of a : {0}", a);

         /* calling a function to get the value */
         n.getValue(out a);

         Console.WriteLine("After method call, value of a : {0}", a);
         Console.ReadLine();

      }
   }
}
```

**ref:**
A reference parameter is a reference to a memory location of a variable. When you pass parameters by reference, unlike value parameters, a new storage location is not created for these parameters. The reference parameters represent the same memory location as the actual parameters that are supplied to the method.

In C#, you declare the reference parameters using the ref keyword. The following example demonstrates this:

```
using System;
namespace CalculatorApplication
{
   class NumberManipulator
   {
      public void swap(ref int x, ref int y)
      {
         int temp;

         temp = x; /* save the value of x */
         x = y;   /* put y into x */
         y = temp; /* put temp into y */
       }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         NumberManipulator n = new NumberManipulator();
         /* local variable definition */
         int a = 100;
         int b = 200;

         Console.WriteLine("Before swap, value of a : {0}", a);
         Console.WriteLine("Before swap, value of b : {0}", b);

         /* calling a function to swap the values */
         n.swap(ref a, ref b);

         Console.WriteLine("After swap, value of a : {0}", a);
         Console.WriteLine("After swap, value of b : {0}", b);

         Console.ReadLine();

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As well as allowing you to reassign someone else's variable to a different instance of a class, return multiple values etc, **using `ref` or `out` lets someone else know what you need from them and what you intend to do with the variable they provide**

- You **don't need** `ref` or `out` if all you're going to do is modify things *inside* the `MyClass` instance that is passed in the argument `someClass`.

  - The calling method will see changes like `someClass.Message = "Hello World"` whether you use `ref`, `out` or nothing
  - Writing `someClass = new MyClass()` inside `myFunction(someClass)` swaps out the object seen by the `someClass` in the scope of the `myFunction` method only. The calling method still knows about the original `MyClass` instance it created and passed to your method
- You **need** `ref` or `out` if you plan on swapping the `someClass` out for a whole new object and want the calling method to see your change

  - Writing `someClass = new MyClass()` inside `myFunction(out someClass)` changes the object seen by the method that called `myFunction`

### Other programmers exist

And they want to know what you're going to do with their data. Imagine you're writing a library that will be used by millions of developers. You want them to know what you're going to do with their variables when they call your methods

- Using `ref` makes a statement of "Pass a variable assigned to some value when you call my method. Be aware that I might change it out for something else entirely during the course of my method. Do not expect your variable to be pointing to the old object when I'm done"
- Using `out` makes a statement of "Pass a placeholder variable to my method. It doesn't matter whether it has a value or not; the compiler will force me to assign it to a new value. I absolutely guarantee that the object pointed to by your variable before you called my method, *will* be different by the time I'm done

### By the way, in C#7.2 there's an `in` modifier too

And that prevents the method from swapping out the passed in instance for a different instance. Think of it like saying to those millions of developers "pass me your original variable reference, and I promise not to swap your carefully crafted data out for something else". `in` has some peculiarities, and in some cases such as where an implicit conversion might be required to make your short compatible with an `in int` the compiler will temporarily make an int, widen your short to it, pass it by reference and finish up. It can do this because you've declared you're not going to mess with it.

---

Microsoft did this with the `.TryParse` methods on the numeric types:

```
int i = 98234957;
bool success = int.TryParse("123", out i);
```

By flagging the parameter as `out` they're actively declaring here "we are *definitely* going to change your painstakingly crafted value of 98234957 out for something else"

Of course, they kinda have to, for things like parsing value types because if the parse method wasn't allowed to swap out the value type for something else it wouldn't work very well.. But imagine there was some fictitious method in some library you're creating:

```
public void PoorlyNamedMethod(out SomeClass x)
```

You can see it's an `out`, and you can thus know that if you spend hours crunching numbers, creating the perfect SomeClass:

```
SomeClass x = SpendHoursMakingMeAPerfectSomeClass();
//now give it to the library
PoorlyNamedMethod(out x);
```

Well that was a waste of time, taking all those hours to make that perfect class. It's definitely going to be tossed away and replaced by PoorlyNamedMethod

Answer (score 4):

ref  and out work just  like passing by references and passing by pointers as in C++.

For ref, the argument must declared and initialized.

For out, the argument must declared but  may or may not be initialized

```
        double nbr = 6; // if not initialized we get error
        double dd = doit.square(ref nbr);

        double Half_nbr ; // fine as passed by out, but inside the calling  method you initialize it
        doit.math_routines(nbr, out Half_nbr);
```

Comment: You can declare a variable inline: `out double Half_nbr`.

Answer (score 4):

**Authoring Time:**

(1) We create the calling method `Main()`

(2) it creates a List object (which is a reference type object) and stores it in the variable `myList`.

```
public sealed class Program 
{
    public static Main() 
    {
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
```

**During Runtime:**

(3) Runtime allocates a memory on stack at #00, wide enough to store an address (#00 = `myList`, since variable names are really just aliases for memory locations)

(4) Runtime creates a list object on heap at memory location #FF( all these addresses are for example sakes)

(5) Runtime would then store the starting address #FF of the object at #00(or in words, stores the reference of the List object in the pointer `myList`)

**Back to Authoring Time:**

(6) We then pass the List object as argument `myParamList` to the called method `modifyMyList` and assign a new List object to it

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();

List<int> newList = ModifyMyList(myList)

public List<int> ModifyMyList(List<int> myParamList){
     myParamList = new List<int>();
     return myParamList;
}
```

**During Runtime:**

(7) Runtime starts the call routine for the called method and as part of it, checks the type of parameters.

(8) Upon finding the reference type, it allocates a memory on stack at #04 for aliasing the parameter variable `myParamList`.

(9) It then stores the value #FF in it as well.

(10) Runtime creates a list object on heap at memory location #004 and replaces #FF in #04 with this value(or dereferenced the original List object and pointed to the new List object in this method)

The address in #00 is not altered and retains the reference to #FF(or the original `myList` pointer is not disturbed).

---

The ***ref*** keyword is a compiler directive to skip the generation of runtime code for (8) and (9) which means there will be no heap allocation for method parameters. It will use the original #00 pointer to operate on the object at #FF. If the original pointer is not initialised, the runtime will halt complaining it can’t proceed since the variable isn’t initialised

The ***out*** keyword is a compiler directive which pretty much is the same as ref with a slight modification at (9) and (10). The compiler expects the argument to be uninitialised and will continue with (8), (4) and (5) to create an object on heap and to stores its starting address in the argument variable. No uninitialised error will be thrown and any previous reference stored will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate the many excellent explanations, I developed the following console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharpDemos
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      List<string> StringList = new List<string> { "Hello" };
      List<string> StringListRef = new List<string> { "Hallo" };

      AppendWorld(StringList);
      Console.WriteLine(StringList[0] + StringList[1]);

      HalloWelt(ref StringListRef);
      Console.WriteLine(StringListRef[0] + StringListRef[1]);

      CiaoMondo(out List<string> StringListOut);
      Console.WriteLine(StringListOut[0] + StringListOut[1]);
    }

    static void AppendWorld(List<string> LiStri)
    {
      LiStri.Add(" World!");
      LiStri = new List<string> { "¡Hola", " Mundo!" };
      Console.WriteLine(LiStri[0] + LiStri[1]);
    }

    static void HalloWelt(ref List<string> LiStriRef)
     { LiStriRef = new List<string> { LiStriRef[0], " Welt!" }; }

    static void CiaoMondo(out List<string> LiStriOut)
     { LiStriOut = new List<string> { "Ciao", " Mondo!" }; }
   }
}
/*Output:
¡Hola Mundo!
Hello World!
Hallo Welt!
Ciao Mondo!
*/
```

- `AppendWorld`: A copy of `StringList` named `LiStri` is passed. At the
  start of the method, this copy references the original list and
  therefore can be used to modify this list. Later `LiStri` references
  another `List<string>` object inside the method which doesn't affect
  the original list.
- `HalloWelt`: `LiStriRef` is an alias of the already initialized
  `ListStringRef`. The passed `List<string>` object is used to initialize a
  new one, therefore `ref` was necessary.
- `CiaoMondo`: `LiStriOut` is an alias of `ListStringOut` and must be
  initialized.

So, if a method just modifies the object referenced by the passed variable, the compiler will not let you use `out` and you should not use `ref` because it would confuse not the compiler but the reader of the code. If the method will make the passed argument reference another object, use `ref` for an already initialized object and `out` for methods that must initialize a new object for the passed argument. Besides that, `ref` and `out` behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

They're pretty much the same - the only difference is that a variable you pass as an out parameter doesn't need to be initialised, and the method using the ref parameter has to set it to something.

```
int x;    Foo(out x); // OK 
int y;    Foo(ref y); // Error
```

Ref parameters are for data that might be modified, out parameters are for data that's an additional output for the function (eg int.TryParse) that are already using the return value for something.

Answer (score 2):

Ref:
The ref keyword is used to pass an argument as a reference. This means that when value of that parameter is changed in the method, it gets reflected in the calling method. An argument that is passed using a ref keyword must be initialized in the calling method before it is passed to the called method.

Out:
The out keyword is also used to pass an argument like ref keyword, but the argument can be passed without assigning any value to it. An argument that is passed using an out keyword must be initialized in the called method before it returns back to calling method.

```
public class Example
{
 public static void Main() 
 {
 int val1 = 0; //must be initialized 
 int val2; //optional

 Example1(ref val1);
 Console.WriteLine(val1); 

 Example2(out val2);
 Console.WriteLine(val2); 
 }

 static void Example1(ref int value) 
 {
 value = 1;
 }
 static void Example2(out int value) 
 {
 value = 2; 
 }
}

/* Output     1     2
```

Ref and out in method overloading

Both ref and out cannot be used in method overloading simultaneously. However, ref and out are treated differently at run-time but they are treated same at compile time (CLR doesn't differentiates between the two while it created IL for ref and out).

Answer (score 2):

There 2 main difference that i want to give example for:

1. `ref` and `out` pass by reference, hense;

```
 class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var original = new ObjectWithMememberList(3);
            Console.WriteLine(original.MyList.Capacity); // 3
            ChangeList(original.MyList);
            Console.WriteLine(original.MyList.Capacity); // 3
        }

        static void ChangeList(List<int> vr)
        {
            vr = new List<int>(2);
        }
}
```

but:

```
 class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var original = new ObjectWithMememberList(3);
            Console.WriteLine(original.MyList.Capacity); // 3
            ChangeList(ref original.MyList);
            Console.WriteLine(original.MyList.Capacity); // 2
        }

        static void ChangeList(ref List<int> vr)
        {
            vr = new List<int>(2);
        }
}
```

and same with `out`.
2. `ref` argument must be an assignable variable.
hense:

```
ChangeList(ref new List<int>()); // Compile Error [might not be initialized before accessing]
```

but:

```
List<int> xs;
ChangeList(out xs); // Compiles
```

Answer (score 1):

Below I have shown an example using both **Ref** and **out**. Now, you all will be cleared about ref and out.

In below mentioned example when i comment **//myRefObj = new myClass { Name = "ref outside called!! " };**
line, will get an error saying **"Use of unassigned local variable 'myRefObj'"**, but there is no such error in **out**.

**Where to use Ref**: when we are calling a procedure with an in parameter and the same parameter will be used to store the output of that proc.

**Where to use Out:** when we are calling a procedure with no in parameter and teh same param will be used to return the value from that proc.
Also note the output

```
public partial class refAndOutUse : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myClass myRefObj;
        myRefObj = new myClass { Name = "ref outside called!!  <br/>" };
        myRefFunction(ref myRefObj);
        Response.Write(myRefObj.Name); //ref inside function

        myClass myOutObj;
        myOutFunction(out myOutObj);
        Response.Write(myOutObj.Name); //out inside function
    }

    void myRefFunction(ref myClass refObj)
    {
        refObj.Name = "ref inside function <br/>";
        Response.Write(refObj.Name); //ref inside function
    }
    void myOutFunction(out myClass outObj)
    {
        outObj = new myClass { Name = "out inside function <br/>" }; 
        Response.Write(outObj.Name); //out inside function
    }
}

public class myClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //int a=10;
        //change(ref a);
        //Console.WriteLine(a);
        // Console.Read();

        int b;
        change2(out b);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.Read();
    }
    // static void change(ref int a)
    //{
    //    a = 20;
    //}

     static void change2(out int b)
     {
         b = 20;
     }
```

you can check this code it will describe you its complete differnce
when you use "ref" its mean that u already initialize that int/string

but
 when you use "out"
it works in both conditions wheather u initialize that int/string or not
but u must initialize that int/string in that function

Answer (score 0):

From the standpoint of a method which receives a parameter, the difference between `ref` and `out` is that C# requires that methods must write to every `out` parameter before returning, and must not do anything with such a parameter, other than passing it as an `out` parameter or writing to it, until it has been either passed as an `out` parameter to another method or written directly.  Note that some other languages do not impose such requirements; a virtual or interface method which is declared in C# with an `out` parameter may be overridden in another language which does not impose any special restrictions on such parameters.

From the standpoint of the caller, C# will in many circumstances assume when calling a method with an `out` parameter will cause the passed variable to be written without having been read first.  This assumption may not be correct when calling methods written in other languages.  For example:

```
struct MyStruct
{
   ...
   myStruct(IDictionary<int, MyStruct> d)
   {
     d.TryGetValue(23, out this);
   }
}
```

If `myDictionary` identifies an `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` implementation written in a language other than C#, even though `MyStruct s = new MyStruct(myDictionary);` looks like an assignment, it could potentially leave `s` unmodified.

Note that constructors written in VB.NET, unlike those in C#, make no assumptions about whether called methods will modify any `out` parameters, and clear out all fields unconditionally.  The odd behavior alluded to above won't occur with code written entirely in VB or entirely in C#, but can occur when code written in C# calls a method written in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass your parameter as a ref then you should initialize it before passing parameter to the function else compiler itself will show the error.But in case of out parameter you don't need to initialize the object parameter before passing it to the method.You can initialize the object in the calling method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but thought of posting. May be a bit more clear than the other answers.

**ref keyword:**

ref is a keyword which is used to pass any value by reference(refer to call by value and call by reference in programming for further knowledge). In short, you declare and initialize a value for example let us say `int age = 5;` so this age is saved in the memory by holding a place of 4 bytes. Now if you are passing this age variable to another method with ref (which means passing them by reference and not by value) then the compiler will just pass the reference of that variable or in clear terms, the memory address of the place where the variable is stored and the called method receives this address and directly accesses the data in that address. So obviously any change to that data will happen also to the variable present in the calling method.

> Example: I give the password of my stackoverflow account and tell him
> that he can do anything he wants, he can ask questions or answer. The
> issue is that, any change he does will directly affect my account.

**Out keyword:**

Out and in are similar to that where they both pass the reference of the variable. Now we know that both need to pass the reference of the variable, it is very clear that there must be a place in memory existing that holds the bytes for the variable. But not initalized in case of out. Becuase the requirement is that, the called method must initialize the value and return it.

> Example: I send the stackoverflow site address to my friend and ask
> him to create an account for me and return the credentials.

**In keyword:**

Now in keyword works exactly the same as ref keyword with only one condition that, the value being passed as reference must not be modified.

> Example: I give the password of my stackoverflow account but telll him
> not to do anything except reading or surfing the site. Not to ask any
> questions, no answers, no votes nothing..

MSDN References:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier

Hope the above is clear.

Answer (score -3):

Mind well that the reference parameter which is passed inside the function is directly worked on.

For example,

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        myObject.Name = "Dog";
        Bar(myObject);
        Console.WriteLine(myObject.Name); // Writes "Dog".
    }

    public void Bar(MyClass someObject)
    {
        MyClass myTempObject = new MyClass();
        myTempObject.Name = "Cat";
        someObject = myTempObject;
    }
```

This will write Dog, not Cat. Hence you should directly work on someObject.

Comment: While everything here is pretty much true it doesn't really explain the difference between by value by reference or out. At best it half explains the difference between reference and value/immutable types.

Comment: If you want that code to write cat please pass that object along with the ' ref ' key like this: public static void Bar(ref MyClass someObject), Bar(ref myObject);

Answer (score -4):

I may not be so good at this, but surely strings (even though they are technically reference types and live on the heap) are passed by value, not reference?

```
        string a = "Hello";

        string b = "goodbye";

        b = a; //attempt to make b point to a, won't work.

        a = "testing";

        Console.WriteLine(b); //this will produce "hello", NOT "testing"!!!!
```

This why you need ref if you want changes to exist outside of the scope of the function making them, you aren't passing a reference otherwise.

As far as I am aware you only need ref for structs/value types and string itself, as string is a reference type that pretends it is but is not a value type.

I could be completely wrong here though, I am new.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Edwin. Strings are passed by reference, just like any other object, as far as I know. You may be confused because strings are immutable objects, so it's not as obvious that they are passed by reference. Imagine that string had a method called `Capitalize()` that would change the contents of the string to capital letters. If you then replaced your line `a = "testing";` with `a.Capitalize();`, then your output would be "HELLO", not "Hello". One of the advantages of immutable types is that you can pass around references and not worry about other code changing the value.

Comment: There are three fundamental types of semantics a type can expose: mutable reference semantics, mutable value semantics, and immutable semantics.  Consider variables x and y of a type T, which has field or property m, and assume x is copied to y.  If T has reference semantics, changes to x.m will be observed by y.m.  If T has value semantics, one can change x.m without affecting y.m.  If T has immutable semantics, neither x.m nor y.m will ever change.  Immutable semantics can be simulated by either reference or value objects.  Strings are immutable reference objects.