# C#: Pointer to double

Tags: c#, pointers, compiler-errors

I have a declaration and in the declaration, I want to set a height is a pointer to a double but get the error mesasage:

> Error 1 Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe
>   context,

Can someone show me the right way to declare the type of pointer in a double ?

Below is mine declaration and I set the height to a pointer of double `(double* height)` but gets an error message.

```
private static extern bool GetElevation(double dLat, double dLon, double* height);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your extern declaration should probably be:

```
private static extern bool GetElevation(double dLat, double dLon, ref double height);
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out) (and accepted answer) might shed some light on the subject. It talks about `ref` vs `out` (not sure which would fit better in your situation) and Marshalling.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should:

1. Learn more about using pointers and what unsafe blocks are in C#, here is a good [resource](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx)
2. Mark your function as "unsafe", see below:

`private static unsafe extern bool GetElevation(double dLat, double dLon, double* height)`

Once all that is done then you can compile with the /unsafe switch.