# Verilog Finite State Machine

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm trying to create a Finite state machine in verilog. The system has 4 `1-bit` *inputs* `rst`, `clk`, `A`, `B` and one *output*, `Z`.

Z is equal to 1 if either:
   A had same value on last two clock edges.

or B has been high (1) on every clock edge since the last rule was true.

Otherwise `z=0`;

I don't have the tools to simulate my attempt atm. So I'm wondering if this is the correct method and if i'm on the right track?

```
module StateMachine( R, A, B, clk, Z);
   input R, A, B, clk;
   output reg Z;

   reg ATemp;
   reg state;

   always @ (posedge clk or A)
      if (A == 1'b1) 
      /////////////////
      begin
         if (ATemp == 1'b1) state <= 1'b1; 
         else ATemp <= A;
       end
       ////////////////
       else
       ////////////
       begin
          if (ATemp == 1'b0) state <= 1'b1;
          else ATemp <= A;
       end


   always @ (state)
      case(state)
         1'b0: Z=0;
         1'b1: Z=1;

         default: Z=0;
      endcase

endmodule
```

Comment: If you don't have simulation tools, then you need to get some. Otherwise this is meaningless, you'll never get anywhere without simulation.

Comment: Why don't you have Sim Tools (most commercial ones provide 30-day demos)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following tools:

[GHDL](http://ghdl.free.fr/) is an open-source simulator for the VHDL language ( [User Guide](http://ghdl.free.fr/site/pmwiki.php?n=Main.UserGuide) )

Additionally these are the most popular simulation **tools**:

- [Active-HDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out)
- [Altera ModelSIM](http://www.altera.com/products/software/quartus-ii/modelsim/qts-modelsim-index.html)
- [Riviera pro ISE simulator](http://www.aldec.com)

**Further resources:**

There is also the [stackexchange electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) community and [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

- [Overmapped](http://www.overmapped.com/): a forum on VHDL topics

Additionally, heed the [C to HDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_to_HDL) compiler tool

(.. I doubt many can review your code in 3 minutes, nor would I want them too )

Answer (score 0):

You have no next state logic so state will never change, and there's no reset so state will start as 1'bz. I recommend starting with [Xilinx guidelines](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/xst.pdf) when coding state machines.

Comment: good starting point (unlike the `everything's fine` answer).

Comment: next state does not need to be defined if state is changed on  a posedge. However in this case it is only ever 1, so will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of a flipflop is slightly wrong. You have `always @ (posedge clk or A)`. You should not combine edge triggers and non-edge triggers. It might work in simulation but you will not get what you want in synthesis.

If you only want the value to change on a clock edge then use `always @( posedge clk)` or for a combinatorial input, that is output changes with input use `always @( A )` or the more modern version `always @*`. @* will trigger for any changes. Missing items from the sensitivity list use to be a main reason for synthesised code not simulating the same as the RTL.

Saying that if you are building a flip flop you should include a reset. `always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n)`

Also note the state is never set to 0, so first impression is that this will lock up into to a particular state/output. It is hard for me to see how the code implements the question being asked. My solution would be some thing like:

```
module statemachine(
  input      rst,
  input      A,
  input      B,
  input      clk,
  output reg Z
);

  reg  [1:0] a_last_two;
  wire      rule_one;

  always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (~rst) begin
      a_last_two <= 2'b0;
    end
    else begin
      a_last_two <= {a_last_two[0] ,A}; 
    end
  end

  assign rule_one = (a_last_two[1] == a_last_two[0]); 
  //rule one could be written as ~^a_last_two (xnor reduction operator)

  reg rule_two;
  always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (~rst) begin
      rule_two <= 1'b0 ;
    end
    else begin
      //rule 2 resets when rule_one is true
      if (rule_one) begin
        rule_two <= 1'b1 ;
      end
      else begin
        rule_two <= rule_two & B ;
      end
    end
  end

  assign Z = rule_one | rule_two ;

endmodule
```