# Out argument of function call should maintain initialized value

Tags: c#, out, ref

I have defined a function where one of the parameters is out. Here, when the function call is made, I pass either a an initialized or an uninitialized argument.
Now, in the case of an initialized argument, how do I make the callee not change the value of the out parameter?

I cant use a ref here because sometimes I do send an uninitialized argument.
Ex:

```
void fun1()
{

    int x = 3;
    fun2 (out x);
    int y;
    fun2(out y);

}

void fun2(out int x)
{

    ...

}
```

Here, I dont want the x to lose the value 3 once control goes to fun2.

Comment: If you put some code to show what you are doing, it would help us visualize how to help you.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you trying to achieve. "out" means that the initialization (and value) is the responsibility of the called method. You are asking for the complete opposite.

Comment: In the example above, I just want to ensure that if the out argument is already initialized in fun1 before fun2 call, it should keep that value intact else, it can initialize the argument in fun2.
But, since it is out, fun2 has to assign a value to the parameter because of which in the first call, the value 3 is lost.\

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you know that int is always initialized to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [out C# - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed, the **called method is required to assign a value before the method returns**.

Since a value must be assigned to the parameter with `out`, you can't save the value in function. It would be better if you make a copy of the variable before calling the function. like:

```
int x = 1;
int backupX = x;
fun2(out x);
```

Comment: That sounds right. Thanks. Which brings me to my next question. What is the difference between ref? and out.

Comment: @TylerDurden, see this question. It has very detailed answer See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out

Comment: I did see that question earlier but it doesnt explain the difference between nullable ref and out

Comment: @TylerDurden, what do you mean by nullable ? `Nullable<int>` or un-initialized `int` ?

Comment: I mean Nullable<int>.
Uninitialized int doesnt exist right because it is by default 0 right?

Comment: if you have `int x;` that is **unassigned** `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I get all wrong, but this sounds like you just want to define a method like this

```
void caller(){
int x=5;
int y = doSomething(x);
}

int doSomething(int x){
 return x+1;
}
```

or in case you want a null state use:

```
void caller(){
int? x=5;
int y = doSomething(x);
}

int doSomething(int? x){
 if (x == null)
    return x;
 return x+1;
}
```

Comment: this is fine only if there is one argument. What if there are more? Which is why I am using ref/out and making the function return type as void

Comment: define classes and use objects in such case