# Loading base class data throught parent class

Tags: c#

I got a class `Fruit` that has a lot of variables: `mass, taste`... etc.
I got a class `Apple` that has a few more variables added to it: `size, texture`... etc.

I wrote a simple function that loads the Fruit variables, and don't want to copy all of it to fill the Apple variables too.

`public void ReadFruitData(string Name, ref Fruit newFruit);`

`public void ReadAppleData(string Name, ref Apple newApple);`

I wish to call `ReadFruitData` from `ReadAppleData`, but not quite sure how to do it, since I can't pass `newApple` as `newFruit`

`class Apple : Fruit`

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: why the `ref` and why can`t you pass the apple to `ReadFruitData`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside ReadAppleData use a temporary variable to do it:

```
Fruit TempFruit = (Fruit)newApple;
ReadFruitData(Name, ref TempFruit);
// carry on with the rest of your code
```

**Note:** This is a workaround to that pesky compiler complaining that `The best overloaded method match for... has some invalid arguments` if you try to send the newApple directly.
**It will not fit any situation.**

As [Patrick Hofman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993547/patrick-hofman) mentioned on the comments, if the `ReadFruitData` assigns a new instance of `Fruit` to the ref parameter, this is not the solution for you. (and in that case you should probably use `out` instead of `ref`).

Here is an example of [when not to use this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zcc1iF) and an example of [when you can use it.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7SBoO6)

Comment: That breaks the `ref`.

Comment: It references `TempFruit`, not `newApple`.

Comment: doesn't matter, they are both referencing the same object

Comment: But if the method inside assigns a new instance, the reference is broken!

Comment: @PatrickHofman If the method inside assign a new instance it should be out, not ref. in that case, this will obviously not work.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Not if it 'updates or creates a new one' depending on the logic. (I do agree `ref` should be omitted)

Comment: If `newApple` is of type `Apple` and `Apple` derives from `Fruit` then `Fruit TempFruit = (Fruit)newApple;` does nothing, and afterwards `ReferenceEquals(TempFruit, newApple)` will return true.

Comment: @PatrickHofman but the OP never wrote 'updates or creates a new one', he wrote 'loads'. I agree that this is not a solution that will fit all scenarios, but I think in this one it fits perfectly, as the OP doesn't need to change the code he is already using.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Correct. this is exactly why this solution will work. It's a simple work-around to prevent the compiler from complaining that there is no overload for `ReadFruitData` that accepts `ref Apple`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've edited my answer to include a "disclaimer", I hope we can agree now that it's a good answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: We can. +1

Answer (score 5):

Well, in fact you can.

If your `Apple` class inherits `Fruit`, you are able to pass in an instance of a deriving type into that method. The actual problem is the use of the `ref` keyword.

Try to write out `ref`. Don't use it if you don't really need to, or use the return value to give back a newly created instance.

If you just update values in `newApple`, you can omit `ref` and it works:

```
public void ReadFruitData(string Name, Fruit newFruit)
{ }

public void ReadAppleData(string Name, Apple newApple)
{
    ReadFruitData(Name, newApple);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `ref` keyword.

You are using an reference type. If you modify the `Fruit` or `Apple` inside those two methods, you modify the original `Fruit` or `Apple`.

If you would have a method where you pass in an `int` or an `bool` without defining them as `ref` parameters and you modify the value inside the method, the value of the original variables will not change.

See:

- [When to use ref vs out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out)
- [MSDN on the `ref` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Comment: Still, you can set the reference to the reference type using `ref`. But in general, you are right. +1

Answer (score -3):

Modify your function definition of 
ReadFruitData(string Name, ref Fruit newFruit) to 
**ReadFruitData(string Name, ref Object newFruit)**

And inside your method, do a cast.

e.g. 
ReadFruitData(string Name, ref Object newFruit)
{
     Fruit myFruit = newFruit as Fruit;
                 OR
     Apple myApple = newFruit as Apple;
}

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: no please don't cast when you don't need it - casts are almost as bad as `null`

Comment: Your answer is really bad. You shouldn't add dependencies to calling methods just to fulfill your own... (I would suggest to delete it)