# The correct way to modify an object that is being passed as a parameter into the modifying class

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

What is the best way of the following 2 suggestions to modify a property on an object that is being modified by a class that accepts the object as a parameter?

1. Have the class work on the object and a return a value which you then assign to the object

or.

1. Pass the object in using the ref keyword and have the class amend the object without actually returning anything.

For example, I have a Person object with a First Name and Last Name and 2 different ways to create the Full Name.

Which is the best way?

```
public static void Main()
{
    Person a = new Person {  FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
    Person b = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };

    NameProcesser np = new NameProcesser();

    // Example A
    a.FullName = np.CreateFullNameA(a);

    // Example B
    np.CreateFullNameB(ref b);
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}


public class NameProcesser
{
    public string CreateFullNameA(Person person)
    {
        return person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName;
    }

    public void CreateFullNameB(ref Person person)
    {
        person.FullName = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `ref`.  Just modify the object in your method.

When an reference type is passed as a parameter, it is passed "by reference", not by value.  So when you modify it, you're actually modifying the original object.  You only need `ref` if you are passing a value type such as an `int`.

I say "by reference" in quotes, because what is actually happening is that an internal "pointer" to the original object is being passed *by value*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Robert. I see what you mean about not needing needing Ref. So modifying the object within the modifying class is preferable to returning a string and then modifying the object.

Comment: See my comment to slapout. This was just an example. In my actual code the object will have a property whose value depends on a webservice call and other processing code, so a getter would not be suitable.

Comment: @RuneFS: Yeah, it's a little weird.  I just didn't want to be bitch-slapped by the folks who read the C# specification with their daily breakfast.

Answer (score 1):

### First things first

The fact that you're mentioning `ref` suggests that you are missing a fundamental notion; that is, code that can access a reference to an object can by definition have access to the *actual* object.

The only conceivable usage scenario in which you would use a `ref` parameter is when you want to set that reference to some other object, or to `null`.

If you don't use `ref` (or even `out` for that matter, see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords)) you are actually passing your argument by value, which means that a copy of it is created.

This means two things, depending on whether the parameter is a **value type** (like int, long, float etc) or a **reference type** (reference to an instance of whatever class).

If a parameter is a value type, a copy of it will be created. Your method can then do whatever it wants to it, because the copy is only limited to that method's scope.

If a parameter is a reference type, however (as your `Person` would be), only the *reference* itself gets copied: the underlying object is the same. This is where the big difference lies. Keep in mind, however, that the reference you have available inside the method is still a copy of the original one, which means that you can set it to `null`, set it to another object and, in short, do whatever you like with it: once the method has returned, that reference will disappear, and the original one will be left untouched.

### That being said

As others told you, there's really no need to use `ref`.

Moreover, as long as you're dealing with trivial cases such as concatenating first and last name, I would let the object itself do it (exactly like Slapout did).

There's always time to separate responsibilities later should such a need arise.

Consider also that having a separate class for such a trivial task might be also considered counterintuitive.
Say this is the code at hand:

```
var p = new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith"} ;

Console.WriteLine(p.FullName);
```

When I do that, I fully expect `FullName` to return something meaningful (i.e. "John Smith") at all times.

With both your approaches, instead, what will happen if I forget (and *I will*) to call `CreateFullName`?

Should you really need to move a given concern into a separate class, hide it inside the property's `get` method.

That way, people won't need to know about the underpinnings of the classes you wrote, and it's still testable.

Comment: Thanks to you (and all others on here) for your prompt and informative replies.

Answer (score 0):

Neither - and you don't need 'ref' - just use:

```
public void CreateFullNameB(Person person) 
{ 
    person.FullName = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, the only reason to separate the method into a other class is if that method have dependencies like database or network access. Otherwise that simple method should be a property of `Person` class.

Also it is only reason to pass whole object to method is when object data is widely used inside that method. Otherwise it is better to pass FirstName and LastName as parameters and return result.

Classes don't need to be passed with `ref` modifier to modify their content. ref is only required if method want assign parameter with a reference to a new instance.

In example you described if choose from two options the return value is better because it makes less coupling and separates logic from data representation. But if few properties of an entity can be updated, then passing object is better.

Comment: You pass and object as an argument not a class

Comment: Hi STO, yes the modifying method does have dependencies and requires multiple values from the object.

Comment: Good, so it have dependencies then it is separated method not a part of Person class. Can business logic of the method **in your project** be applied without knowledge about `Person`: if yes then probably you shouldn't use Person as parameter. And then result - can result be used outside Person class - if yes it is probably better to return scalar value otherwise you can update person passed as argument.

Comment: Hi STO, yes I see what you mean. Thanks.