# What is the difference between ref and out?

Tags: c#

while am trying with ref keyword by replacing out key word there is no error in the below code.while am trying to use out instead of ref there occur an error like"**Unassigned OUT Parameter**" 
What does this error mean ?

```
   static void Main()
    {
        string test = "34";
        addOneToRefParam(out test);
        Console.WriteLine("test is : " + test);
    }

    public static void addOneToRefParam(out string i)
    {
        int  k =Convert.ToInt32(i) + 1;
        i = Convert.ToString(k);
        Console.WriteLine("i is : " + i);
    }
```

Comment: I wish there was a searchenginge which could find answers to questions like this. I bet the URL would look like this https://www.google.com/search?q=csharp+ref+out

Comment: @derape that's an impressive UI mockup, too; kudos. Someone should make that.

Comment: Minor aside: as far as the CLI is concerned: "absolutely nothing". There is precisely zero difference between `ref` and `out`, except that one happens to have an attribute on it that it isn't interested in. All differences here are *entirely* at the compiler level.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords

Comment: You neither need `ref` since you don't modify it  nor `out` since you need it as input parameter. You just want `string i`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords                                                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ref` parameters must be initialized before passing to function,the parameter may or may not be changed by the function.So you need to initialize it before you pass, like you do with *non-ref* arguments:

```
int i; 
Foo(i); // error unassigned variable
Foo(ref i) // same error
```

For `out`, your function guarantees that it will set the argument to a value.So it doesn't need to be initialized.