# What is the purpose of the "ref" and "out" keywords in Vala?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, vala

How and when should these keywords be used?

Do they have the same purpose as in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Parameter_Directions) suggests they are exactly the same as in C#:

- **'out' from the caller side**: you may pass an uninitialised variable to
  the method and you may expect it to be initialised after the method
  returns
- **'out' from callee side**: the parameter is considered uninitialised and
  you have to initialise it
- **'ref' from caller side**: the variable you're
  passing to the method has to be initialised and it may be changed or
  not by the method
- **'ref' from callee side**: the parameter is considered
  initialised and you may change it or not