# C# method out parameter list initialization doesn't works with Clear()

Tags: c#, list, initialization, out

I found, that construction

```
Method(out List<T>list)
{
    list.Clear();      // doesn't allowed to initialyze List<T>list
    list = null;       // is accepted by VSTO, however, is not so good
}
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: `out` parameters are generally for things that are created WITHIN the method, not for modifying things passed INTO the method. Perhaps you should be using `ref`. You need to show the context in which this code will be used.

Comment: Thanks Mattew! In fact, I'm handling into the method the list field in the class, like
    public List<string>str = new List<string>();
    ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use unassigned parameter withing this method. There is simple rule: use [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) whether parameter is not initialized or use [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if you pass initialized parameter to method.

This code will run correctly:

```
void Method<T>(ref List<T> list)
{
    list.Clear();
    list = null;
}
```

Read more about differencies in this question: [What's the difference between the 'ref' and 'out' keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `out` semantics, not `ref`, you have to instantiate your list:

```
Method(out List<T>list)
{
    list = new List<T>();
}
```