# C# Fmod System::CreateChannelGroup returns ERR_INVALID_PARAM

Tags: c#, fmod

I get something reason unknown error.
from System::CreateChannelGroup function in C#

```
private void FmodERRCheck(Fmod.RESULT result){
    if (result != RESULT.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Fmod.Error.String(result));
    }
}

private void InitFmodSystems()
{
    Fmod.Factory.System_Create(out system);
    system = new Fmod.System(IntPtr.Zero);
    system.init(3, INITFLAGS.NORMAL, IntPtr.Zero);

    channelGroup = new ChannelGroup(IntPtr.Zero);

    FmodERRCheck(system.createChannelGroup("", out channelGroup));
}
```

the variables declared top on class.
I was written InitFmodSystems() method to initailize fmod system.

```
FmodERRCheck(system.createChannelGroup("", out channelGroup));
```

this line return to me 'ERR_INVALID_PARAM' error.
what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is passing `IntPtr.Zero` to the `System` constructor. In FMOD, you use `FMOD_System_Create` to get the pointer for a `System` object, and with that you can pass it to the other functions, or in the C# wrapper, to the constructor.

Working code would look like this:

```
Fmod.Factory.System_Create(out IntPtr handle);
System system = new Fmod.System(handle);
```

In the FMOD C# wrapper, you cannot pass `IntPtr.Zero` to any of the "core" class constructors, that is an invalid handle, it is expecting a valid handle returned by the "create" functions within the `System` class.

So after you properly created the `System` object (see above example), you would then create a `ChannelGroup` as such:

```
FmodERRCheck(system.createChannelGroup("", out IntPtr channelGroup));
ChannelGroup group = new ChannelGroup(channelGroup);
```

Answer (score -1):

you are initialiseing the channelGroup variable.
When using an out parameter you cannot use an initialized variable.

So it must be something like this.

```
ChannelGroup channelgroup;
FmodERRCheck(system.createChannelGroup("", out channelGroup));
```

in this example the channelGroup variable stays unassigned until it goes into the function as an out parameter.

**EDIT**

Its possible that the empty string for the name parameter is also not allowed. but the initialized out parameter is also a problem.

Comment: This answer is just wrong on multiple levels... Passing an initialized parameter to `out` is perfectly acceptable. In addition, a ChannelGroup does not have to be given a name, its an optional parameter then can even be set to `null`.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords

Comment: @ForeverZer0 if you try to write to console the out parameter in the first line of the method, in c# method, it wont even compile. regardless if you set the value before entering calling the method that have the out parameter.  try and compile this:     class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int myInt = 40;
            GetSOmethingFromOutParam(out myInt);
        }

        private static void GetSOmethingFromOutParam(out int myInt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myInt);
            myInt = 50;
        }

    }

Comment: Yeah, because, it only should be `out myInt`, not `out int myInt` within the method call if it is already initialized. You can't add the `int` again. Trust me, it is very possible, done all the time, and confirmed by the docs.