# what is the value that is passing into the called method when "out paramater" is passed

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, out

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 10;

    Program th = new Program();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() => thread2(out i));
    t2.Start();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() => thread1(i));
    t1.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits." + i);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void thread1(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i = 100;
}

static void thread2(out int i) // what should be the value of i???
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    i = 21;           
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

what should be the value received in called method while we are passing out parameters?? "whether it is zero or the value we are passing"

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? What happened?

Comment: Are you asking what an `out` parameter is?

Comment: The ticked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords) will help

Comment: I don´t understand your question. You *have* to give every out-param a value before leaving the method. Or are you asking which `i` will be modified by `thread2`? Try it out and you´ll see.

Comment: thanks guys i got answer for my question

Comment: @JagadeeshBevara - please do accept upvote answer if helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 10;

    Program th = new Program();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() => thread2(out i));
    t2.Start();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() => thread1(i));
    t1.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits." + i);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

First function thread2 will receive value `i = 10` . but

in Second function you will either receive `i =10 or i =21` , because its all depends on execution done at CLR/CPU level.

what I mean to say here is if you `thread2()` method execution get finished before it reaches to execution of `thread1()` then `thread1()` will receive `21`. But if excution not get finished then receive `10` as input.

above is true if you remvoe this line  `Thread.Sleep(5000);` from your  `thread2()` function.

But if you dont than 10 will get passed to both function and main thread print 10 in ideal scenario , but this also depends on context switching ...your ouput is not fixed here. it all on processing and execution.