# How can I return an object that has been modified inside a method?

Tags: c#, software-design

I'm developing with C#, Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Framework 4.7.1.

My program do a lot of calculations, and I don't want to create new Collections to store them. So, I have created a collection to reuse it (the only thing that I'm going to do is change the collection's content):

```
List<List<double>> offsprings;
```

Inside the following method I will clean the contents of `offsprings` parameter to not create new `List<double>`:

```
public void GlobalRecombination(
    List<List<double>> population,
    List<List<double>> offsprings,
    int numOfObjectVariable,
    int numOfStrategyParameters,
    RecombinationType objVarRecomType,
    RecombinationType straParamRecomType)
{
    foreach (List<double> offspring in offsprings)
    {
        offspring.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfObjectVariable; i++)
        {
            double newValue = 0.0;

            [ ... ]

            offspring[i] = newValue;
        }

        int total = numOfObjectVariable + numOfStrategyParameters;
        for (int i = numOfObjectVariable; i < total; i++)
        {
            double newValue = 0.0;

            [ ... ]

            offspring[i] = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Which is the best way to return `offspring` parameter?

Now, the method works, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the 'ref' and 'out' keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords)

Comment: I'm going to go with "neither". You have a class with a field here that's struggling to get out.

Comment: "Inside the following method I will clean the contents of offsprings parameter to not create new List<double>" And what is the purpose *behind* this? You are aware that by clearing the original list and adding new items you´re effectivly creating a new list anyway. So if you really want to share the same reference you don´t have to do anything, as all your updataes to the list are reflected to all references to it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Have you seen the code? I'm not creating anything new and I'm not destroying any object.

Comment: Do you want to return `offspring`( a single element), or `offsprings` (the list)?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have posted the code to show you what I'm doing.

Comment: @ste-fu I'm not asking about what is the different between ref and out. This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Your code is working and borderline acceptable. Changing the contents of a parameter container is unwise and probably a negative optimization. Putting that parameter at position 2 and nor marking it in the name in any way is a bad design.

Comment: There´s no simple answer, it depends on what clients of your API do with those lists. As you seem to completely rebuild your data-structure I´d consider to indicate this at least via some documentation or even better via the methods name. `ref`-  and `out` may or may not be a solution, depending on the context. Having said this your question is quite borad and opinion-based.